# MySQL crashed and was not able to restart until clearing a table

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have MySQL running on my Ubuntu server and suddenly the MySQL Daemon was down.
When trying to restart it, the restart failed due to

```
xxx table is marked as crashed and last (automatic ) repair failed
```

So then I have to truncate the table, restart MySQL and everything was fine. We had backups so we were able to recover.

Any idea why this happens and how to check what caused this?

Comment: can you check if anything was logged in MySQL error log ?

Comment: check kernel.log or dmesg, usually that sort of bad things happens with OOM killer or hardware faults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the error log, which would usually record a crash stacktrace . The location can be found with:

```
$ mysql -e 'show variables like "log_error"'
+---------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                    |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| log_error     | /var/log/mysql/error.log |
+---------------+--------------------------+
```

The cause can be anything from a bug in a storage engine to faulty hardware. If it repeats, you could enable query logging and try to determine whether a particular query is causing the crash.

Also, check whether you are using the latest stable mySQL packages.